# MySQL table file gets bigger when adding index, but not smaller when removing index

Tags: mysql

I am experimenting with MySQL to see how the file size is growing when adding index to it and a lot of data and so on.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (
    a TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    b TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
```

After adding 1 million rows on a simple two column TINYINT table with no indexes, the test_table size (test_table.ibd) was 36 MB using InnoDB as engine.

The query for adding data:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_procedure;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure
(IN loop_amount INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE rand_max INT DEFAULT 254;
    DECLARE a, b, c INT;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    TRUNCATE TABLE test_table;
    WHILE i < loop_amount DO
        SET a = RAND() * rand_max + 1;
        SET b = RAND() * rand_max + 1;
        INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (a, b);
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL test_procedure(1000000);
```

After adding a single index on b like this:

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ADD INDEX (b);
```

The file test_table.ibd grew to 48 MB. It makes sense that it grows when adding an index to it.

After I drop the index like this:

```
DROP INDEX b ON test_table;
```

And confirming that there are no indexes on the table with the statement:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM test_table;
```

I see that the file test_table.ibd is still 48 MB.

I tried doing

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE test_table;
```

Now the test_table.ibd is 40 MB, but not 36 MB as it started out without index.

It goes back to 36 MB only if I truncate the table and add 1 million rows running the stored procedure above.

Why does it not go back to it's original size? How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using InnoDb with the option `innodb_file_per_table`.

In which case you can run `optimize table test_table` and that should free the unused space.

The documentation states: "When you run an OPTIMIZE TABLE, InnoDB creates a new .ibd file with a temporary name, using only the space required to store actual data.  When the optimization is complete, InnoDB removes the old .ibd file and replaces it with the new one." (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html)